# Position Circles Based on Desired Overlap

Tags: geometry, circles

I apologize in advance for my crude drawings and my limited knowledge. I have had little to do with math in 40+ years.

This question is about positioning two circles where they overlap by a known percent of the areas of the circles.

Two circles represent some objects.

[image: MDS Distance = 75]

A represents 2 objects.
B represents 3 objects.
One object is shared by A and B.
Therefore there are 4 total objects, of which 3 are not shared.

Using MDS and converting to percentages, the distance between the center of the circles is 75: (3/4)*100

Now I want to change the radii of the circles to correspond to the numbers of objects they represent:

[image]

What I was expecting was that the area of the intersection would be proportional to the percent of objects they represent. In other words, I expected 50% of C to overlap D because 50% if it's objects (1 of 2) are shared. Likewise, I expected 33% of D to overlap C because 33% of D's objects (1 of 3) are shared with C. Something like this:

[image]

It turns out that the MDS distance by itself does not position them correctly. So what I need is something like this:

Given two intersecting circles of known radii, and where the radii are determined by a common measure, what distance apart do their centers need to be for them to intersect a given percent of their respective areas?

Thanks for your time, and I hope I made my issue clear.

Comment: The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, where $r$ is the radius. So if you want the area of the circle to be proportional to the number of objects, choose a radius proportional to the *square root* of the number of objects.

Comment: Thanks, however I already have that. The radii are determined by the number of objects each represents. What I need is how far apart the circles should be in order for the area of the intersection to reflect the number of objects they have in common.

Comment: Your radii are 50 for 2 objects, and 75 for 3 objects. Which means that the smaller circle has $1250\pi$ units squared of area per object,  while the larger one has $1875\pi$ per object. So area does not consistently represent a number of objects.

Comment: Aha, I think you discovered that I am doing this backwards Frank. It sounds like I should be starting with circles whose areas are based on the percentages of the total, and derive the radii from them! Thanks for the insight, I'll explore this.

Answer (score 1):

The area of intersection $A$ between two circles of radius $r$ and $R$ with their centers at distance $d$ is the [area of the asymmetric lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(geometry)) forming the intersection of the two circles,
$$\begin{aligned}
A &= r^2 \arccos\left(\frac{d^2 + r^2 - R^2}{2 d r}\right) \\
~ &+ R^2 \arccos\left(\frac{d^2 - r^2 + R^2}{2 d R}\right) \\
~ &- \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(d+r+R)(d+r-R)(d-r+R)(-d+r+R)} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Unfortunately, I cannot find an algebraic solution for $d$ for a given $A$, $r$, and $R$.

We do know that when $d \ge r + R$, $A = 0$.

We also know that when $0 \le d \le \lvert r - R \rvert$, $A = \pi \min(r^2, R^2)$, since the circles are close enough for the larger one to completely cover the smaller one.

In between these two extremes, $A$ is monotonic with respect to $d$, so a *numerical* solution is easily found using a binary search in $d$ within the above range.

Here is a Python implementation:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from math import acos, sqrt, pi

def find_distance(area, r, R, epsilon=0.001):
    if r <= 0 or R <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot solve for a single disk.")
    elif area < 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot solve for negative intersection area.")
    elif area == 0:
        return r + R

    smallerarea = pi * min(r*r, R*R)
    if area >= smallerarea:
        # We assume > is only due to rounding errors, and behave
        # as if we had been given area == the area of the smaller circle instead.
        return abs(r - R)

    dmin = abs(r - R)
    dmax = r + R
    while True:
        d = 0.5*dmin + 0.5*dmax
        if d - dmin <= epsilon or dmax - d <= epsilon:
            return d

        A = ( r*r*acos((d*d + r*r - R*R)/(2*d*r))
            + R*R*acos((d*d - r*r + R*R)/(2*d*R))
            - 0.5*sqrt((d+r+R)*(d+r-R)*(d-r+R)*(-d+r+R)) )

        if A > area:
            dmin = d
        elif A < area:
            dmax = d
        else:
            return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import stderr, argv, exit

    if len(argv) != 4:
        if len(argv) > 0 and len(argv[0]) > 0:
            this = argv[0]
        else:
            this = "(this)"

        stderr.write("\n")
        stderr.write("Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n" % this)
        stderr.write("       %s R1 R2 F\n" % this)
        stderr.write("\n")
        stderr.write("This calculates the distance between centers\n")
        stderr.write("of two disks with radii R1 and R2, such that\n")
        stderr.write("the area of intersection is fraction F of the\n")
        stderr.write("area of the smaller disk.\n")
        stderr.write("\n")
        exit(0)

    r1 = float(argv[1])
    if r1 <= 0.0:
        stderr.write("%s: Invalid disk radius.\n" % argv[1])
        exit(1)

    r2 = float(argv[2])
    if r2 <= 0.0:
        stderr.write("%s: Invalid disk radius.\n" % argv[2])
        exit(1)

    f = float(argv[3])
    if f < 0 or f > 1:
        stderr.write("%s: Invalid fraction.\n" % argv[3])
        exit(1)

    print("%.3f" % find_distance(f * pi * min(r1, r2)**2, r1, r2, 0.00025))
```

The `epsilon` parameter described the largest difference in the distance that we consider insignificant.  Because the above example shows the distance using three decimal digits, it uses `0.00025`.  In general, if the smallest unit you care about is `d`, then `d/4` is a good value for `epsilon` here.

For example, if you want to know what the distance is between a disk with radius $3$ and another with radius $5$ so that the intersection is one quarter of the area of the smaller one, run

`python3 -B example.py  3 5 0.25`
and it will happily tell you the distance needed is `5.972`.

Note the code is intended to be easily understood and experimented with, and is not the most efficient way to do the binary search; but it also does not waste much or do much unnecessary work, so it is not too inefficient either.

Note that if the intersection covers fraction $F_\min$ of the area of the smaller circle, the area of intersection is $\pi F_\min r_\min^2$.  Since the area of the larger circle is $\pi r_\max^2$, the fraction of the larger circle the intersection covers is $F_\max$, $$F_\max = \frac{F_\min \pi r_\min^2}{\pi r_\max^2} = F_\min \frac{r_\min^2}{r_\max^2} = F_\min \left(\frac{r_\min}{r_\max}\right)^2$$
i.e. the smaller fraction times the square of the ratio of the smaller radius to the larger radius.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response Glarbo. This looks like it is correct for my scenario, but as Frank Seidl pointed out above, my premise for the size of the radii and the resulting circle areas appear to ensure that the desired result is impossible.

Comment: @LenWhite: That's closely related to that last snippet in my answer as well: choosing the fraction of overlap for one circle, defines the fraction of overlap for the other.  Thus, you do need to consider how the circle radius and area, and the area of overlap, relates to the quantities you wish to express, given how the unavoidable $(r_1/r_2)^2$ factor keeps popping up everywhere in this. Anyway, I do love the idea of trying to describe quantities more intuitively, so even if this ended up not being usable approach, I still had fun discovering how to do it!